# I get set attribute error when using tinymce angular

Tags: angular, ckeditor, tinymce

I'm having a problem with rendering the editor component from tinymce angular into different dialog boxes ... in my case I have 4 different dialog boxes that I can switch from and the editor opens for the first dialog that I open but when it comes to click on the 2nd,3rd ..it gives me the ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined
    at i.aria (theme.min.js:1) error.
Can t seem to figure out what's the problem.

Comment: Please add some sample code to work with. It would be great if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can use [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) to create one.

Answer (score 0):

The app is pretty complex but my guess is that somehow I m not doing the init correctly
Here a pic with my ngOnInit function for the tinymce component https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAg3s.png